# Jupyter unable to use Vartests that’s found in my site-packages

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have Anaconda installed in my system. I have used Jupyter notebook to install vartests package using “!pip install vartests”. In my site-packages folder inside Anaconda/lib, I am able to find a directory for vartests, which means the package has been installed. But when I try to import it in the same jupyter notebook, it says import error.
I’ve tried using “!{sys.executable} -m pip install vartests” but it doesn’t help. I’ve followed things written in “Installing Python Packages from Jupyter Notebook” by Jake VanderPlas as well.
One thing, my “!type -a python” doesn’t give me anything. Is there a way out from this?

Comment: I don't know if it will help in your situation here, but you should be aware the use of an exclamation point with `pip install` is outdated. The magic command `%pip`, and also related `%conda`) was added to insure the installation with `%pip install` occurs in the environment backing the current notebook where you are running the install command. Use of the exclamation point alone doesn't do this. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more about the modern `%pip` and `%conda` install commands.

Comment: So, just to try out I installed python 3.9 and pip installed vartests from cmd line terminal. Still doesn’t work. I’m hoping there is nothing wrong with vartests itself

Comment: There is something wrong with vartests itself. You can post [an issue at the site about it](https://github.com/rafa-rod/vartests/issues). You can tell them they can reproducibly see what you describe by going [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and pressing `launch binder` to get a session served by MyBinder. Then running `%pip install vartests` in the session. It seems to install correctly but as you point out, the import statements faile. That session has Python 3.8.

Comment: I reported the issue in the link given above. The authors resolved them and have updated the version in pip. Thank You Wayne for your help.